# Unable to select the components on a page

Tags: components, aem, rollout

I want to perform a rollout only for the selected components in the page. I noticed that I am not able to select any of the components presented in the pages using the small checkbox in the component's edit bar.

I am not sure why this is happening. All of them are custom components and not OOTB ones.

Any solutions to this, please share them.

Comment: Are you able to do this on a standard Geometrixx site in your instance? Are you able to do it with standard OOTB components? What's the difference between them & your templates / components? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, No, I'm unable to check even the geometrixx site components. Not much of a difference in the templates. It is created in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that in EditBar.js, the listener associated with the checkbox was not functioning. The following loc can be found at /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/EditBar.js if not overlayed.

```
listeners: {
            check: function(cb, checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    CQ.WCM.select(editBar, true);
                } else {
                    CQ.WCM.deselect(editBar, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

It worked when the '**check**' event was changed to '**selectionChanged**' . Clearing the browser cache, reload the page to see the changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no **selectionChanged** event, so it doesn't work correctly when e.g. rollout is used, it should be changed to:

```
listeners: {
    check: function(cb, checked) {
        if (checked) {
            CQ.WCM.select(editBar, true, true);
        } else {
            CQ.WCM.deselect(editBar, true, true);
        }
    }
}
```