# can't do rollout selected components function in aem

Tags: aem, rollout

[image]

I can select component by changing Editbar.js as mentioned below link. 
[Unable to select the components on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317413/unable-to-select-the-components-on-a-page)

but after checking components that I want to rollout, then select rollout selec ted components, but keep getting alert message saying that you have to select at leaste one component.

why why? T_T

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the component(s) *after* you select the "Rollout selected components" option and before you click the "Next" button.